# What's wrong with this steganography extract code?

Tags: matlab, extract, steganography

I want to try extracting message from images that have been inserted messages before..but there is an error with the description bellow..

this code extract :

```
% Read Image Stego
IS = imread('imagestego.bmp');

% Extract RedChannel
RedChannel = IS(:,:,1);

% Convert RedChannel to biner
bitstego = uint8(reshape(dec2bin(RedChannel,8)',1,[]) = '0');
nBitstego = length(bitstego);

% Extraction
extBits = bitget(RedChannel(1:end),1).';
extMessage = char(bin2dec(reshape(int2str(extBits),8,[]).').');
```

and this error from extract code :

```
>> latihanextract
Error: File: latihanextract.m Line: 8 Column: 55
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

and this is embedding code before..it's work!

```
coverImage = imread('foto1.jpg');
message = 'IMRON';

%EMBEDDING
RedChannel = coverImage(:,:,1);
GreenChannel = coverImage(:,:,2);
BlueChannel = coverImage(:,:,3);
bits = uint8(reshape(dec2bin(message,8)',1,[]) - '0');
nBits = length(bits);
RedChannel(1:nBits) = bitset(RedChannel(1:nBits),1,bits);
Imageresults = cat(3,RedChannel,GreenChannel,BlueChannel);
imwrite(Imageresults,'imagestego.bmp');
```

so what's the problem ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but in the code where you have the error instead of `message` you have `RedChannel` on line 8

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan That's because the code getting the error is trying to **extract** the bits from `RedChannel` instead of **inserting** the bits of `message` into the image.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] as text not as a screenshot. Also, try to read and understand your code and use the matlab debugger to analyse why the error occurs, i.e. inspect your variables and check why you are asking an index that exceeds matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

Here's your problem...

```
% Read Image Stego
IS = imread('stegosaurus.bmp');

% Extract RedChannel
RedChannel = IS(:,:,1);

% Convert RedChannel to binary
bitstego = uint8(reshape(dec2bin(RedChannel,8)',1,[]) - '0');
nBitstego = length(bitstego);
% the previous 2 lines are actually unnecessary and can be deleted...
% see explanation in text below

% Extrication
extBits = bitget(RedChannel(1:end),1).';   % (1:end) gives you all of the elements
extMessage = char(bin2dec(reshape(int2str(extBits),8,[]).').')
```

You were trying to loop over the number of bits in the image instead of the number of bytes. `bitstego` is the binary representation of all of the bytes in `bitstego`, so `bitstego` is 8 times as long as `RedChannel`.

It's much easier in this case just to take the number of elements in `RedChannel` using the special index `end`.

Comment: Ah, that was a typo. If you look at line 8 you'll see that my code originally had a `=` where yours had a `-`. The `-` was correct. And as I said, lines 7 & 8 are not even needed with the update to line 12, so you could even just remove them.

Comment: Note that you're still going have a problem in the last line if the number of pixels in the image (rows*columns) is not evenly divisible by 8.

Comment: So the code should be like this?
bitstego = uint8(reshape(dec2bin(RedChannel,8)',1,[]) - '0');

Comment: but i get the new error message :

this new error message :

Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 8, not divisible into total number of elements, 100.

Error in latihanextract (line 13)
extMessage = char(bin2dec(reshape(int2str(extBits),8,[]).').')

Comment: See my comment about "divisible by 8".

Comment: so in the last line, 8 should change to (rows*columns) or how ?
sorry..i'm new user in matlab..

Comment: It depends on what you want to happen with that last (incomplete) byte. Probably the easiest is to pad it with zeros since it's unlikely to be part of the message, right?

Comment: i try delete code for line 7 and 8..and then run program latihanextract..but get error message like this :

>> latihanextract
Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 8, not divisible into total number of elements, 100.

Error in latihanextract (line 13)
extMessage = char(bin2dec(reshape(int2str(extBits),8,[]).').');

Comment: Yes. That's the error we've been discussing that happens because the number of bytes is not divisible by 8. You need to do something to `extBits` to make its size divisible by 8. Then that last line will work. I'm not going to tell you how to do that because 1) I don't know for sure *how* you want to handle this case, 2) you probably need to figure this one out for yourself, and 3) we've fixed the error that you originally asked about. Try solving this problem on your own and if you are still having trouble, post a new question.